# WPLM - first url dosnt show language

Tags: wordpress, wpml

My url is coming without the language like "www.website.com" I need to force to come with the user language puting [www.website.com/pt](http://www.website.com/pt) or [www.website.com/en](http://www.website.com/en) (its wordpress)

I did a redirect in javascript but, its a bit weird and i cant find a way to do it on the pluign or on php code....

Someone can help me?

Thanks

"I create a javascript to redirect to the url i need on the first enter"

Comment: Welcome! There is a checkbox in settings that does exactly this: **WPML > Languages > Different Languages in directories > Use directory for default language checkbox**. [Documentation on the site](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/directory-default-language/) is pretty clear and easy to find

Answer (score 0):

Check to have the language in the URL all the time:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hello! So, its activated but dosnt work, my actual website still enters on ".com" on URL but still assumes .com/pt/

Since my user browser is EN, i wold like to redirect to this folder right on he enters on the website, if they choose another language okay...

Thnaks for this image